# Running MediaPipe Pose Landmarker in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, mediapipe, tflite, pose-detection

In my iOS application in React Native, I'm trying to set up the MediaPipe pose landmarker model. Since there's no direct guide for the iOS platform here [developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/pose_landmarker](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/pose_landmarker), I extracted `pose_detector.tflite` and `pose_landmarks_detector.tflite` models from `pose_landmarker_full.task`. Then, I used the `vision-camera-fast-tflite` library to run `pose_landmarks_detector.tflite`.

I managed to get some data. It looks like the model can detect some changes in movement, but the output landmarks are mostly totally incorrect. Any ideas?
[Detection example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SJNI.jpg)

I went through guides for multiple platforms and also tried to examine the MediaPipe framework written in Python to see if some preprocessing or postprocessing is going on. However, I still don't have any reasonable explanation of why the model output is incorrect.